Grassmann algebras, spinors, and Fermions
A Fermionic quantum field theory $\psi$ has half integer spin, and thus, $\psi$ is a spinor taking values in $\mathbb{C}^m$. On the other hand, the spin-statistics theorem tells us that these fields are anti-commuting and thus take values in a Grassmann algebra. This suggests that the most general form of a spinor field is
$$x \mapsto \psi(x) = \psi^i(x) (v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n) \tag{1}$$
where $i$ is the spinor index. In index free notation, (1) can be written as a tensor product:
$$x \mapsto \tilde{\psi}(x) \otimes v \tag{2}$$
where $\tilde{\psi}(x)$ is the vector with components $\psi^i$ as in (1) and $v$ is an arbitrary element of the Grassmann algebra.
Is this correct? If so then I have some further questions:

Why is the Grassmann algebra part of the field $(v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n)$ often omitted in physics textbooks when discussing Fermionic theories and is only brought up when the path integral is introduced? It seems too fundamental to leave out.
How are Lorentz transformations defined for these fields? If $\Lambda$ is an arbitrary Lorentz transformation, then, I suspect, using the index free version (2), that $\Lambda$ should actually be written as the tensor product of representations $\Lambda \otimes I$ where $I$ is the trivial representation on the Grassmann algebra and $\Lambda$ transforms the spinor part $\psi$ as spinors usually do under Lorentz transformations.
How is the vector space and its dimension $n$ in (1) chosen when defining the Grassmann algebra? Will any vector space work?

For my third question, I think the dimension should always be infinite, but I'm not sure why. I have made a separate post about this that can be found here. I have also taken a look at this related question about Grassmann algebras and spinors.

Hi CBBAM. Are you following a reference? Which page?

@Qmechanic I am not following any particular reference. Would you like me to find a reference for anything in my post?

Comment to the post (v1): 1. The notation $n$ seems to be used in 2 different meanings. 2. Also the question seems to be mainly about Grassmann variables rather than spinor variables.

@Qmechanic Thanks for catching that, I have edited my post so $n$ only have one meaning.


Why is the Grassmann algebra part of the field $(v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n)$
often omitted in physics textbooks when discussing Fermionic theories and is only brought up when the path integral is introduced? It seems too fundamental to leave out.

I will only comment on the above question, given the the other questions are already taken care of.
The Grassmann-ness only matters if you have multiplication between spinors. The fermion field $\psi$ is governed by the Dirac equation, where there is NO multiplication between $\psi$. In other words, the Dirac equation equation is linear in $\psi$ and Grassmann-ness would NOT matter in the Dirac equation. Therefore Grassmann-ness is usually omitted in physics textbooks when discussing Fermionic theories in the context of the Dirac equation. And for that matter , Grassmann-ness is also omitted in the discussion of spinor representation and spinor Lorentz transformation, based on the same "linear" argument.
Then why does Grassmann-ness matter in the path integral? Well, you may have already guessed, there are multiplications between spinors in the path integral in the form of spinor Lagrangian/Action.
A good example where Grassmann-ness matters is the charge conjugation of scalar $\bar{\psi}\psi$
, which involves multiplication between spinors. As you can verify (see here), without the Grassmann-ness of $\psi$
you can NOT even prove the charge conjugation invariance of $\bar{\psi}\psi$!

Thank you! When you say that Grassmann-ness is omitted in the discussion of spinor Lorentz transformation, does this mean that the Grassmann algebra is given a trivial representation of the Lorentz group?

Yes, the Grassmann algebra is trivial/invariant under the Lorentz transformation.

Thanks for all the help!
